# Scala: How to reuse other arguments for another parameter value in class constructor

Tags: scala, class

Can I reuse specific argument for another constructor parameter?

```scala
case class Foo(bar: Int, buzz: Int = bar) // does not compile!

Foo(42) // => I want Foo(42, 42)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can overload `apply` method in companion object `Foo`.

```scala
case class Foo(bar: Int, buzz: Int)
object Foo {
  def apply(bar: Int): Foo = Foo(bar, bar)
}

Foo(42) // => Foo(42, 42)
```

Comment: You can Google `auxiliary constructor` for normal classes.